# jQuery ui autocomplete stay focus on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the this autocomplete, so far everything is good, but I was wondering how can I make the focus to stay if we mouseout.. I mean if I type something and mouseover to it they will be gray background on that focus and if I mouseout it will return to white, I want it to stay gray background. in other words I want the hover to stay.

this is an example how I want it to be http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/ but for some reasons I want to use jquery ui autocomplete.

I don't think this is possible with css ? so..

demo http://jsfiddle.net/2wyqjhmk/

code

```
$.widget("ui.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    options: {
        maxItems: 9999
    },
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var that = this,
            count = 0;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (count < that.options.maxItems) {
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            }
            count++;
        });
    }
});


$(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        maxItems: 10
    });
});
```

Comment: you could add a class to the li that matches the previously selected li.

Comment: not good at javascript, maybe do a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-menu-item.selected {
    background: pink;
}
```

Determine the previous selected li, find it and add the selected class. This should allow for custom styling of the UL that is shown when you type.